# "Staying at my aunt's place" or "staying with my aunt"?

Tags: grammar, expressions, prepositions

Are both of these sentences correct? Is there any difference in meaning between them?

"I'm staying with my aunt."

or

"I'm staying at my aunt's."

What I mean is "remain at her place temporarily." The "with" sentence does not seem to be very common and I would probably run across it mostly in British texts but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You are effectively raising three questions, of grammar, of semantics, and of dialect/ idiom. Too broad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They differ possibly, "I'm staying at my aunt's" implies your aunt own(s) where you are staying and she may (or may not) be staying there too.

The other simply states the you and your aunt are "staying" together, and speaks not as to the ownership of the place.